# From browser how to browse a link which needs priviledged IP address

Tags: security, ssh, browser, ip, tunnel

From my local machine from home, I can not access this site. But I can ssh to my work machine and from there ssh to this machine hosting this site. Is there a way to do this ssh hopping to change IP address and be able to access this site from local machine?

I am using Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up ["SSH Port Forwarding" or "SSH Tunnelling"](http://www.openssh.com/faq.html#2.11)

Answer (score 2):

ssh to the ssh server using:

```
 ssh -D8080 <server ip/name?
```

Then in your browser settings, use a SOCKS proxy, and set the IP address to `127.0.0.1` and the port to `8080`.

This will use the remote server as a proxy server accessed across an ssh tunnel.